# check if array of dates is within range of dates in python

Tags: python, pandas, date, range

I have an array of dates that should be between 09-2021 and 09-2022. How do I check if every single one of the dates is in the range?

e.g
Below are some of the dates within the array

```
calendar202109['date'].dt.date.unique()
array([datetime.date(2021, 9, 16), datetime.date(2021, 9, 17),
       datetime.date(2021, 9, 18), datetime.date(2021, 9, 19),
       datetime.date(2022, 9, 15)], dtype=object)
```

Comment: You may want to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can you please provide more context code, like your imports and how you got the dates

Comment: I have a csv file with 7 columns: listing_id, date, available, price, adjusted_price, minimum_nights, maximum_nights
```
calendar202109 = pd.read_csv("calendar-202109.csv") 
calendar202109['date']= calendar202109['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
calendar202109['date'].dt.date.unique()
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using *pandas*. Looks like overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) directly for that:

```
a = array([datetime.date(2021, 9, 16), datetime.date(2021, 9, 17),
           datetime.date(2021, 9, 18), datetime.date(2021, 9, 19),
           datetime.date(2022, 9, 15)], dtype=object)

((a > pd.Timestamp('2021-09-01')) & (a < pd.Timestamp('2022-08-31'))).all()
```

output: `False`

To identify the outliers:

```
m = ((a > datetime.date(2021, 9, 1)) & (a < pd.Timestamp('2022-08-31')))

a[~m]
```

output: `array([datetime.date(2022, 9, 15)], dtype=object)`

*NB. using here `pd.Timestamp('2021-09-01')` as a convenience, you can use `datetime.date(2021, 9, 1)` instead.*

Answer (score 0):

Without the aid of *pandas* you could just do this:

```
from datetime import date

list_ = [date(2021, 9, 16),
         date(2021, 9, 17),
         date(2021, 9, 18),
         date(2021, 9, 19),
         date(2022, 9, 15)]

lo_bound = date(2021, 9, 1)
hi_bound = date(2022, 8, 31)

for d in list_:
    if not lo_bound <= d <= hi_bound:
        print(d, 'Out of range')
```

**Output:**

```
2022-09-15 Out of range
```